# Razor in VSCode | How to automate the search and collection of all variables within a .cshtml file, before compilation to HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

Let's say I have a Razor file (*example.cshtml*) containing the following lines of code, and that **I can only work on VSCode without access to debugging tools**:

```
@{ string testString = "test1";
   bool testBool = false;
}
```

Is there any way I can "scan" the file and collect all the manually declared variables (testString and testBool in this case) and their values ("test1" and false in this case), so that I can then display them? I know I can do this manually and see the values once the HTML is compiled:

```
@testString @testBool
```

But I'd like this (the scan and collection of variables) to be automated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to work around this.

The PageData object, always present in a Razor page and of type *IDictionary<object, dynamic>*, contains a list of all variables used within that page.

Dictionaries can be iterated via the *foreach* loop to access all keys and values of the items they contain:

```js
@foreach (KeyValuePair<object, dynamic> var in PageData)
{
    <p>@var.Key = <b>@var.Value</b></p>
}
```

This will output a neat list of all variables used within a specific page.